# I am getting path not found error but the path correct

Tags: vbscript

When i run this script i am getting this error path not found in

```
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strpath)
```

Can anyone help what to change in the code?. My path was correct, but it keeps giving me this error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the folder doesn't exist or you don't have access?  Can you try putting \doc\DavWWWRoot\RegulationandCorpComms\Regulation and Corp Comms Library\Corp Comms\External Press Monitoring\2016 into the address bar of Windows Explorer and make sure you can navigate to the folder (and that it exists).

Comment: I can navigate to the folder i can see the foders inside that and i tried with local folder also shows same error

Comment: try using strPath="C:\" and just see if the GetFolder() call works with that.

Comment: how are you running the script?

Comment: when i put C:\ its not showing any error... i am running this task scehduler and that stuck at running so when i open this code it shows error so may be becuase of this error its got stuck i am checking on that

Comment: also confirm the user account used for the task (in the "Security options" section).  That account needs access to the share you are trying to get to on \\doc

Comment: This is not the new script its running from past 3 years but donno suddenly got this error

Comment: Hey i put msgbox(strpath) in the below of strpath then its woring but when i put below set ObjFolder its not working can help need to change set objfolder ??

Comment: any idea about this

Answer (score -1):

Have you made certain that is the correct path you are looking for

Make certain to check for missing \'s as well

`strpath= "\\doc\DavWWWRoot\RegulationandCorpComms\Regulation and Corp Comms Library\Corp Comms\External Press Monitoring\"+yr`

Comment: When debugging what does (strpath) equal?  It's most likely a formatting error, an permissions error. 

As another commenter said try navigating to the address within your file explorer and see if it exists.  

If it does try copying the path and pasting it into the strpath variable.

Comment: Is there any chance to change that line to anyother

Comment: @avi Which line?  The filepath itself or the variable name?

Comment: Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder (strpath) this line i am getting error but strpath showing crrectly i use msgbox(strpath) but this line shows error is there option to change this line to some other thing

Comment: @avi What is the exact error you are receiving and what is the value of strpath when you step to that line using the debugger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123999/discussion-between-avi-and-confusedandamused).